# How to pass input value to Request validation class in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, forms, http, request, laravel-5

I have one controller and one Form Request Validation class: `app\Http\Controllers\GuestController.php` and `app\Http\Requests\ItemValidation.php`. In `GuestController.php` I use `storeItem(ItemValidation $request)` method to store item data which comes from `<form>` .

And in `ItemValidation.php` request class I redirect back to the form with following method if validation fails.

```
public function response(array $errors){
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($errors)->withInput()->with('type', '2');
}
```

The main thing I want is to pass value from `<form>` (which is entered by user in form) to `response` method. I tried with following but it did not work:

```
public function response(array $errors, Request $request){
            return Redirect::back()->withErrors($errors)->withInput()->with('type', '2')->with('sub_menu_id',$request->sub_menu_id);
    }
```

Comment: did you alter (add) routes Route::get("/response", "GuestController@response"), pointing to controller? And pass form via post or get to that url?

Comment: Sorry, you did not get my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`->withInput()` flashes the previous input to the session.

In your form view, you should use the `old()` helper to repopulate the value if a previous input exists.

Blade:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}">
```

Plain PHP:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?= e(old('username')) ?>">
```

If there is no previous input, it returns null, which echoes as an empty string.

Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#old-input